# How to Find/Replace text in a textbox Word using QAxObject (Automation with Qt)

Tags: c++, qt

I wonder if anyone could help me with this...Finding text and replacing (in MS Word) was just simple until I have tried it in a textbox. The text out of the textbox is replaced, but the text IN the textbox couldn't be replaced.I have found many answers about this subject, but they are all unuseful when you're working with Qt (QAxObject, QAxBase...), it's really too complicated, and needs a professional. This is the code that I'm using to find/replace text (that not work for textboxes):

```
int main(int argc,char *argv[]){
    QApplication app(argc,argv);

    QAxObject *wApp = new QAxObject("{000209FF-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}");
    QAxObject *wDoc = wApp->querySubObject("Documents");
    wDoc->querySubObject("Open(QString)","aURL to the .docx file");
    QAxObject *wActive = wApp->querySubObject("ActiveDocument()");
    QAxObject *wContent = wActive->querySubObject("Content");
    QAxObject *wFind = wContent->querySubObject("Find");

            bool bMatchCase      = true;
            bool bMatchWholeWord = true;
            bool bMatchWildCards = false;
            bool bReplaceAll     = true;

            QString old = "Text";
            QString New = "NewText";

            QVariantList vA;

    vA = { old, bMatchCase, bMatchWholeWord, bMatchWildCards, false, false, true, 1, false,New, bReplaceAll ? "2" : "1" };

    wFind->dynamicCall("Execute(QString,bool,bool,bool,bool,bool,bool,int,bool,QString,int)",vA);
    wApp->setProperty("Visible",true);
    wDoc->dynamicCall("Close(bool)",true);
    return app.exec();
}
```

Source : https://forum.qt.io/topic/82574/how-to-find-replace-text-in-a-docx-file-using-qaxobject/3

And thanks for your help.